# Google and Facebook federeated identities with AWS Amplify return "Error: Cannot retrieve a new session. "

Tags: reactjs, oauth, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

i have added federated identities to my React.js application and all worked good initially, however after a few hours the user is not able to log back in. -->  "Error: Cannot retrieve a new session. Please authenticate."

I am using a very basic setup :

```
            <Button onClick={() => {
              Auth.federatedSignIn({provider: 'Facebook'})
            } }> Login with Facebook</Button>
</div>
```

````
  Auth: {
    mandatorySignIn: true,
    region: config.cognito.REGION,
    userPoolId: config.cognito.USER_POOL_ID,
    identityPoolId: config.cognito.IDENTITY_POOL_ID,
    userPoolWebClientId: config.cognito.APP_CLIENT_ID,
    oauth: {
      domain: "domain.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com",
      redirectSignIn: 'http://localhost:3000/',
      redirectSignOut: 'http://localhost:3000/',
      responseType: "token"
    }
}```

To me, the issue is related to the expiration of the user token. However, i am not sure what would be the approach to fix this. I read so many posts about that issue but could not find a solution.
````